# Is there a way to run a single DAG for multiple environments in one run?

Tags: airflow, environment, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG which runs multiple KubernetesOperators.
These operators perform tasks on Clusters(which are Environments). Is there a way to trigger these tasks for all the clusters in one run?
Is there a concept of ENVIRONMENTS in Airflow that would allow us to run the same DAG for different environments?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you need to do? Say you have 3 environments A, B and C. Do you want to trigger 3 (dynamically created) DAG runs in parallel (one DAG run for each environment) with the DAG having one task that would run a pod on a given environment? Or do you want a single DAG run that would create 3 tasks (one DAG run in total with 3 (dynamically created) tasks for each environment to be ran in parallel)?

Comment: The 2nd case, where one DAG triggers the task for all 3 environments and runs in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to run a single dag for 3 regions on prod env.
But, there is only a single region on dev/stg env.

I can put additional tasks to dag for multiple regions.
But, I want to run the same code for dev/stg/prod env.
For this, I should trigger my dag for each environment.

I made another dag to trigger my legacy dag.
New dag do only triggering
I also changed 'max_active_run' of my legacy dag to 3.

With this option, I can run my dag sequentially/parallelly for multiple regions.